# Insert into database array buffer

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please tell me,  how do I properly send a query to the database from Node.js code so that the insertion of the value is successful?

The request structure that I need (from SQL Server Management Studio):

```
INSERT INTO [db].[Employee]([ID], [NAME], [TYPE])
VALUES (<ID, MICBINID>, <NAME nvarchar(120)>, <TYPE, MICBINID>)
```

Existing row example from DB:

```
0x002554778996547896555558745734852612    Mike Ross     0x00179314626849513971917683426984
```

I want to transfer the creation of an ID for a new line to the base by using `NEWID()` command.

And I need to pass the identifier (array) of the TYPE in the request from the existing one.

My sql request:

```
let TYPE = "CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX)," + type + ")";
let sql = "INSERT INTO [db].[Employee] (ID, NAME, TYPE) VALUES (NEWID(), '" + NAME + "', '" + TYPE + "')";
```

But no matter how I change the variation of the type ID conversion, the error is always the same

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: You don't tell us which SQL library you're using from Node, e.g.: msnodesql, msnodesqlv8, tedious, etc.. Have a read through the [msnodesqlv8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8) page to see how parameter binding works.

Comment: i use require("mssql")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`request.input()` function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type-value) to specify input parameters, their types and their values.

For the `mssql` module you want to supply a Buffer object with the `sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX)` type, which looks like the following:

```js
pool.request()
    .input("data", sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX), binaryData)
    .query("insert dbo.Demo (BinaryData) values (@data)");
```

A complete example:

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

const config = {
    database: "StackOverflow",
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        enableArithAbort: true
    },
    password: "YourP4ssw0rdHere",
    port: 1433,
    server: "YourServerNameOrIpAddress",
    user: "YourSqlLogin"
};

const binaryData = Buffer.from([
    0x00, 0x25, 0x54, 0x77, 0x89, 0x96, 0x54, 0x78,
    0x96, 0x55, 0x55, 0x58, 0x74, 0x57, 0x34, 0x85,
    0x26, 0x12
]);

let pool = null;
console.log("Connecting...");
sql.connect(config)
    .then((newpool) => pool = newpool)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Dropping...");
        return pool.request()
            .query("drop table if exists dbo.Demo");
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Creating...");
        return pool.request()
            .query("create table dbo.Demo ( ID int not null identity(1,1), BinaryData varbinary(max) )");
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Inserting...");
        return pool.request()
            .input("data", sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX), binaryData)
            .query("insert dbo.Demo (BinaryData) values (@data)");
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Selecting...");
        return pool.request()
            .query("select * from dbo.Demo");
    })
    .then((select) => {
        console.dir(select);
        console.log(`${JSON.stringify(select.recordset)}`);
    })
    .then(() => pool.close())
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        pool.close();
    });
```

Which results in:

```sh
% node stackoverflow.js
Connecting...
Dropping...
Creating...
Inserting...
Selecting...
{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { ID: 1, BinaryData: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ]
}
[{"ID":1,"BinaryData":{"type":"Buffer","data":[0,37,84,119,137,150,84,120,150,85,85,88,116,87,52,133,38,18]}}]
```